# Understanding database dimension and cube dimension

Tags: ssas

Can anyone please explain a database dimension and cube dimension in SSAS in simple terms? I have done my research and I am not sure I completely understand the differences between the two.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are developing an Analysis Services Multidimensional model in Visual Studio. That project represents a database. In that database are top level objects like data sources, data source views, cubes and dimensions. So the dimensions you put in the Dimensions folder in Solution Explorer are "database dimensions".

Next, when you construct a cube it contains measure groups and cube dimensions. The bottom left of the first tab of the cube designer lists the cube dimensions. Also the rows on the Dimension Usage tab list cube dimensions.

You can add a database dimension to a cube one or more times. For example, if you have a Date dimension defined as a database dimension then you can add it multiple times to the cube to make Order Date and Ship Date cube dimensions. These multiple copies of the dimension are called "role-playing dimensions".

The database dimension takes up storage space. The cube dimensions don't take up duplicate storage space for the dimension data. But measure groups are indexed by cube dimensions so each additional cube dimension will increase the index size in your cube.

Answer (score 0):

The cube dimension is the role the data plays in your cube.  The most frequently used is Date.  You'll have multiple dates in your cube, Order Date, Hire Date, Termination Date, etc.  Each of these 'role playing' dimensions acts the same and can contain the same attributes, but they differ in how they describe the relationship to the event you are looking at.

The database dimension is the storage for the cube dimension.  There is only one Date database dimension and all of your cube Date dimensions will use the exact same copy of the data.  All of the attributes used by your cube dimension are contained in the database dimension, even if the various cube role-playing dimensions do not each make use of all of the attributes.  Changing data in the database dimension will change the data in all of the cube dimensions when the cube is next processed.